# conditional grouping based on another grouping

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's say I have 3 groups, 4 advisors, and 3 clients:

```
group_id advisor_id client_id assets
1        1          1         100
1        2          2         200
2        3          
3        4          3         300
```

Can you assist in getting:

```
count groups with 1 advisor_id (=2)
count groups with > 1 advisor_id (=1)
count clients for groups with 1 advisor_id (=1)
count clients for groups with >1 advisor id (=2)
```

I tried variations of:
`select case when count(advisor_id) over(partition by group_id)=1 then count(distinct group_id) end`

and

`select case when count(advisor_id)=1 then count(distinct client_id) end`

but these don't give me what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use multiple aggregation.  For instance, for the first two, I would use a histogram-of-histograms query::

```
select cnt, count(*), min(group_id), max(group_id)
from (select group_id, count(distinct adviser_id) as cnt
      from t
      group by group_id
     ) t
group by cnt;
```

You specifically care about "1" or "more than 1".  For that, I might phrase this as:

```
select sum(case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as only_1,
       sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as more_than_1
from (select group_id, count(distinct adviser_id) as cnt
      from t
      group by group_id
     ) t;
```

Comment: For clients, I need to do `count(distinct case when cnt=1 then client_id else 0 end)` but it for some reason counts null client_id, even if I do `count(distinct case when cnt=1 and client_id is not null then client_id else 0 end)`. Any ideas? I can't put a where client_id is not null..